# How to fix (apparently invisible) dependency conflict on Gradle?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, exoplayer

I'm trying to compile an Android React Native project, but I'm dependency issues after enabling Exoplayer for `react-native-video`.

Here are the type of errors I'm getting:

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.smoothstreaming.DefaultSsChunkSource
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.smoothstreaming.DefaultSsChunkSource, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

or

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.exoplayer2.C$ColorSpace
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.exoplayer2.C$ColorSpace, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I understand that this is a dependency conflict issue, so I try running `./gradlew app:dependencies` to try and find where's the issue, but apparently only `react-native-video` uses Exoplayer. So I'm at a loss on how to fix this.

Here's the output for my dependencies:

```
+--- project :react-native-spinkit
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4
|    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 -> 27.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0
|    |    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|    |    |    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    |              \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.facebook.fbui.textlayoutbuilder:textlayoutbuilder:1.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.facebook.fbui.textlayoutbuilder:staticlayout-proxy:1.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0
|    |    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:drawee:1.3.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|    |    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|    |    |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:1.3.0
|    |    |         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    |         +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|    |    |         \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:1.3.0
|    |    |              +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    |              \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.3.0
|    |    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0 -> 3.9.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0
|    |    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|    |    |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:1.3.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0 -> 3.9.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.6.0
|    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0 -> 3.9.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0
|    |    \--- org.webkit:android-jsc:r174650
|    \--- com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0
+--- project :react-native-view-shot
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
+--- project :react-native-blur
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:[0.32,) -> 0.55.4 (*)
+--- project :react-native-firebase
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2
+--- project :react-native-version-number
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
+--- project :react-native-fabric
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
|    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5 -> 2.9.0
|         +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.2
|         +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.6.0
|         |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.2
|         |    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1
|         +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.7
|         \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1
+--- project :react-native-keep-awake
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
+--- project :react-native-billing
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
|    \--- com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1 -> 27.1.0
+--- project :pushwoosh-react-native-plugin
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1 -> 0.55.4 (*)
|    +--- com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh:5.5.8
|    +--- com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-amazon:5.5.8
|    +--- com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-badge:5.5.8
|    +--- com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-gcm:5.5.8
|    +--- com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-inbox:5.5.8
|    +--- com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-inbox-ui:5.5.8
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+ -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+ -> 26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:design:26.+ -> 26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:transition:26.1.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
|    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1
|    |    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:gifdecoder:4.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2 -> 27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:disklrucache:4.3.1
|    |    \--- com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.3.1
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.60
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.60
|    |         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+ -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+ -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+ -> 16.0.3
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:[16.0.1] -> 16.0.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.2] -> 16.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.2.1] -> 16.2.1
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.2] -> 16.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.0.0 -> 17.0.0
|    |    |    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.0
|    |    |    |    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 -> 16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.0.0 -> 17.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.2] -> 16.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.2.1] -> 16.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:[16.0.1] -> 16.0.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.2] -> 16.0.2
|    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[16.0.3] -> 16.0.3 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.2.1] -> 16.2.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+ -> 17.3.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[17.0.0] -> 17.0.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:16.0.0 -> 17.0.0 (*)
+--- project :react-native-sound
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:0.12.+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
+--- project :react-native-orientation
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
+--- project :react-native-fbsdk
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
|    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+ -> 4.36.0
|         +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.36.0
|         |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|         |    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         |    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|         |    |         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|         +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.36.0
|         |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.36.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0
|         |    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0
|         |    \--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0
|         +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.36.0
|         |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.36.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.36.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|         +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.36.0
|         |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.36.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.36.0 (*)
|         +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-places:4.36.0
|         |    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.36.0 (*)
|         +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:4.36.0
|         |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.36.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0 (*)
|         +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:4.36.0
|         |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.36.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0 (*)
|         \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:4.36.0
|              +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.36.0 (*)
|              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2 -> 27.1.0
+--- com.loginradius.android:androidsdk:4.0.1
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1 -> 4.36.0 (*)
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0 -> 3.9.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1
|    +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1
|    |    \--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1 -> 2.1.0
|    |         \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0
|    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0 (*)
|    |    \--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.7
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
+--- project :react-native-config
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
+--- project :react-native-image-crop-picker
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
|    +--- com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.1-native
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1 -> 3.9.1 (*)
|    \--- id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0
|         \--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0 (*)
+--- project :react-native-video-exoplayer
|    +--- com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.7.3
|    |    +--- com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0 -> 27.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0 -> 27.1.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1 (*)
+--- project :react-native-svg
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
+--- project :react-native-linear-gradient
+--- project :react-native-vector-icons
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
+--- project :react-native-device-info
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+ -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:15.0.1
|    +--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:palette-v7:26.1.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary:ccl:2.9.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0 -> 26.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.8.0 -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.55.4 (*)
+--- com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0
|    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|    \--- com.facebook.fresco:animated-base:1.3.0
|         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|         +--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:1.3.0 (*)
|         \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:1.3.0 (*)
+--- com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.3.0
|    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.3.0
|    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|    |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:1.3.0 (*)
|    \--- com.facebook.fresco:animated-base:1.3.0 (*)
+--- com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.3.0 (*)
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0 (*)
+--- com.zopim.android:sdk:1.3.6.1
|    +--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0 -> 26.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:design:24.0.0 -> 26.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.zopim.android:sdk-api:1.3.6.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0 -> 27.1.0
|         +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7 -> 2.8.1
|         +--- com.zendesk:belvedere:1.1.1.1
|         |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|         \--- com.zendesk:java-common:1.9
+--- com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:+ -> 3.1.0+58
+--- com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+ -> 3.1.0+58
+--- com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-chromecast:+ -> 3.1.0+58
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:11.8.0 -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary:ccl:2.9.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 -> 16.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:15.0.1
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[16.0.1] -> 16.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 -> 16.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1 -> 16.0.3 (*)
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:16.0.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 -> 16.0.1 (*)
     \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 -> 16.0.1 (*)
```

Related issue on `react-native-video` repo: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/1205

Answer (score 2):

Exclude support library from **exoplayer** dependency because its already present in project.

You can exclude it like below code

```
implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.X.X') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Comment: Right, that could be a possible solution, but I found rthat the issue is that another dependency (JWPlayer) brings Exoplayer built-in. Do you know how can I exclude  specific modules (such as `source.smoothstreaming`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you know which dependency is the culprit, the [`dependencyInsight` report](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html#example_using_the_dependency_insight_report_for_a_given_dependency) might give you a better view of this as it can be focused on a single dependency.